# jQuery how to loop function

Tags: jquery, loops, callback

I want to fadeOut the first div every few seconds, this code works once:

```
$('.comment:first').delay(4000).fadeOut();
```

and to try and make it run continually I've been trying to do a callback function or loop but finding no joy. I'm not familiar with these types of functions. Here is my attempt so far:

```
$('.comment:first').delay(4000).fadeOut( function(){
                $(this).delay(4000).fadeOut();
});
```

**EDIT:**
After div.comment:first is faded out, the second div.comment would now be first in line so I want to then fadeOut that div and continually run that function. I do not want the first div.comment to ever fade back in. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Does it fade in as well? Because if the first div is faded out, there is no need to call the method again.

Comment: can't fade it out continually without un hiding it

Comment: I have added a better description of what I want. I want the first div to fade out, and then fadeOut the next div that takes it place to fadeOut as well. I have a row of 30 divs and I want the function to run until all of the divs have faded out.

Comment: +1 now that's a question! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will stop on the last element as you need it to
(otherwise remove the `if` and use `.eq(++C % N)` ! :)

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/acejuy/3/edit)*

```
$('.comment:gt(0)').hide();   // hide all but first one
var N = $('.comment').length; // count comments
var C = 0;             // just a useful counter

function loop(){
     if(++C < N){       // this will prevent the loop to run infinitely
         $('.comment').delay(1000).fadeTo(400,0).eq(C).fadeTo(400,1,loop);
     }
}

loop();
```

Loop explained:

```
$('.comment')           // all comments...
    .delay(1000)        // wait for some time and...
    .fadeTo(400,0)      // fadeTo 0
    .eq(C)              // just, the one which index equals to preIncremented C
    .fadeTo(400,1,loop) // fade him to 1 and callback the LOOP !
;
```

**EDIT**

 After the OP leaved me a comment:

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/acejuy/6/edit)**

```
var N = $('.comment').length;
var C = -1;

function loop(){
     if(++C < N)
     $('.comment').eq(C).delay(1000).slideUp(400, loop);
}

loop();
```

Comment: +1 - this is the correct way of doing it where you use animation chaining and the completion function of the last animation to restart the loop.

Comment: Hi roXon, that's nearly there the only difference is I want all my divs to be visible by default. Then only hide one at a time. My layout is 2 rows of divs, when the first one is hidden then the second one takes its place and a div from the bottom row fills in the gap on the first row. Sorry if this is confusing. Thanks

Comment: @ClintonGreen added a new demo, next time help us to help you in the question! ;) happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `setInterval`:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('.comment:first').fadeOut();
}, 4000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use an interval

```
window.setInterval(function(){ $('.comment:first').fadeOut(); }, 4000);
```

To make it togglefade:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
 if( $('.comment:first:hidden').length > 0 ){
   $('.comment:first').fadeIn();
 }else{
   $('.comment:first').fadeOut();
 }
}, 4000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that gets called repeatedly from complete callback of second animation which needs to show the element after it has been faded out.

```
var $commentFirst=$('.comment:first')

function fadeDiv(){
   $commentFirst.delay(4000).fadeOut( function(){
          /* fade it back in, call function again when done*/
          $commentFirst.delay(4000).fadeIn(fadeDiv);
   });

}
/* on page load*/
$(function(){
    fadeDiv();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The fadeOut function can be called this way (http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/):

```
.fadeOut( [duration ] [, complete ] )
```

I haven't used it for a while but I'd say that you should
1) write the duration as first parameter
2) use as callback a function that fades the div back in

Then in the callback of the fadeIn point back to the original function that launches the fadeOut, this way you'll have a cycle FadeOut > FadeIn > FadeOut > ...